# PHP find difference between two linux time

Tags: php, mysql, linux, datetime, time

I'm trying to get the difference between two linux times.  I want to show the difference in months.   I am getting one Linux time from the database and comparing it against `time();`.

```
$sql_sms_transactions = "SELECT MAX(`sendtime`) FROM `sms_transaction`  where customer_id='$customer_id'";

    $result_sms_transactions = mysql_query($sql_sms_transactions);
    while($row2=mysql_fetch_assoc($result_sms_transactions))
{

    $status = $row2['MAX(`sendtime`)'];

    //print $status;
    $month = date('m', $status); // 1-12
    $year = date('YW', $status);
    //print $month;
    //print $year;

    $current=time();
    $monthcurrent = date('m', $current); // 1-12
    $yearcurrent = date('YW', $current);

    //print $monthcurrent;
    //print $yearcurrent;

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Answer (score 2):

Using [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateInterval`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) objects, this should work:

```
$date1 = new DateTime();
$date1->setTimestamp($timestamp1);

$date2 = new DateTime();
$date2->setTimestamp($timestamp2);

$diff = $date1->diff($date2);
// Result of type DateInterval
echo ($diff->y*12) + $diff->m
```

From what I understand of your code, you have to do this beforehand:

```
$timestamp1 = time();
$timestamp2 = $status;
```

Comment: thanks for your reply its not working it shows nothing,can you change the code regarding my code pls

Comment: Did you set `$timestamp1=time()` and `$timestamp2` ?